# Can't make PUT /raylight/v1/documents/id/parameter/id work properly

Tags: api, rest, business-objects

I need to update document parameters via REST API.

I've tried using the following:

```
PUT .../raylight/v1/documents/33903/parameters/3
```

with the following `json` payload

```
{
    "parameters":{
        "parameter": {
            "id": 3,
            "answer": {
                "values": {
                    "value": [
                        "2019/9"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the returned answer shows unmodified parameters:

```
{
    "parameter": {
        "@optional": "false",
        "@type": "prompt",
        ...
        "id": 3,
        ...
        "answer": {
            ...
            "info": {
                ...
                "previous": {
                    "value": [
                        "2015\/12"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "values": {
                "value": [
                    "2015\/12"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I properly set new prompt parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:
`PUT .../raylight/v1/documents/33903/parameters`

instead of:
`PUT .../raylight/v1/documents/33903/parameters/3`

Adding a parameter ID at the end performs a different function: it returns the list of parameters that are dependent upon the one provided.  You have only one in this case, and it's returning itself.  Leave it off, to refresh the document.

Comment: That's strange that they provide a PUT method which doens't PUT.. Using PUT on on `.../parameters` seems to work